# Double integrals - polar coordinates - how do I determine the boundaries for $r$ and $\phi$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I need to calculate the surface bounded by:

1. $(x-1)^2 +y^2=1$
2. $y=x$
3. $y=0$

and I have to do it using polar coordinates. Now, letting $x=r\cos{\phi}$ and $y=r\sin{\phi}$, $\phi \in [0, 2\pi]$, $r \in [0, \infty)$, we have:

1. $ 0 \le r \le 2\cos{\phi}$

This is obvious because the area needs to be inside of the circle

2. $r\sin{\phi} = 0$
3. $\sin\phi = \cos\phi$

I know that the boundaries when we integrate by $dr$ are $0$ and $2\cos\phi$, but how can I deduce the boundaries for $\phi$?

The "equals" sign doesn't help in $2.$ and $3.$, because, for example, in $2$, both $r$ and $\sin\phi$ can be zero.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The main hint: draw a picture.

Comment: @GEdgar I drew a picture before I introduced polar coordinates, I don't know how to draw one now. I solved the exercise without using polar coordinates (albeit I get a tedious integral) but I don't know how to do this. I know that $sinx = cosx$ for $\pi/4 + n\pi$ but that's about it

Answer (score 1):

Picture
[image: pict]
$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ is a circle, $y=x$ is the slanted line, $y=0$ is the horizontal line.

The two lines are $\theta = \pi/4$ and $\theta = 0$.  We look a the picture to see that the values we want for $\theta$ are from $0$ to $\pi/4$.
The area we want
is $0 \le \theta \le \pi/4, 0 \le r \le 2\cos\theta$.
The double integral for the area is
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\cos\theta} r\;d r\;d\theta
$$

We have to remember that $dx\,dy$ becomes $r\,dr\,d\theta$ because the Jacobian for the change of variables is $r$.

Comment: Thanks very much! I understand now, but I have just one more question:

How do we know that the line y=x is pi/4? do I calculate it as I would with complex numbers: angle is $\arctan{y/x}$

Comment: For points on the line, we have $y/x = 1$ so compute $\arctan 1$.  Also, we want the first quadrant, so that tells us which branch of arctan.